# Twitter Bootstrap: how to display icon on <ol>

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

See: http://jsfiddle.net/D4eu9/1/

```
<p><i class="icon-envelope"></i> foo@foobar.com</p>
<ol>
    <li>one@foobar.com</li>
    <li>two@foobar.com</li>
    <li>three@foobar.com</li>    
<ol>
```

Say I want icon-envelope to appear to the left of the first `<li>`. I want it to appear and align with the first icon-envelope shown. How do I do this?

**Update 1: what it should look like **

```
[icon] foo@foobar.com

[icon] one@foobar.com
       two@foobar.com
       three@foobar.com
```

Comment: Why do you want it aligned to the first icon envelope? It's conceptually wrong. If you use <ul> you must expect that indentation. Otherwise put each e-mail address inside <ul>

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for, either. You seem to want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/TMjhb/1/, which would be an <ol> with no indentation?

Comment: I've updated my answer, check pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `<i>` tag inside the `LI`

```
<i class="icon-envelope"></i> one@foobar.com
```

So your full code will be this way:

```
<p><i class="icon-envelope"></i> foo@foobar.com</p>
<ol>
    <li><i class="icon-envelope"></i> one@foobar.com</li>
    <li><i class="icon-envelope"></i> two@foobar.com</li>
    <li><i class="icon-envelope"></i> three@foobar.com</li>    
<ol>
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/ht7Es/

---

We generally do this way, using `padding`:

```
<p><i class="icon-envelope"></i> foo@foobar.com</p>
<ol>
    <li><i class="icon-envelope"></i> one@foobar.com</li>
    <li class="no-icon">two@foobar.com</li>
    <li class="no-icon">three@foobar.com</li>    
<ol>
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/ht7Es/2/

Comment: I don't want it on all the list items, just the first one. If you remove all but the first one, you end up with the first list item indented, then subsequent list items not. Looks weird.

Comment: Seems hackish. Is there a way to do this in the `<ol>` or perhaps before the `<ol>`?

Comment: Else, you can do this way, using padding. Updating the answer, please wait.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<li><i class="icon-envelope"></i>one@foobar.com</li>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdzQL/)

**UPDATE:**
To move the icon to the top level you need to add margins to the both icon and list item:

```
<li>
    <i style="margin-left:-25px" class="icon-envelope"></i>
    <span style="margin-left:25px;">one@foobar.com</span>
</li>
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5SkJ/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ol>
  <li class="list"><span><i class="icon-envelope"></i> foo@foobar.co</span></li>
  <li class="list"><span><i class="icon-envelope"></i> foo@foobar.co</span></li>
  <li class="list"><span><i class="icon-envelope"></i> foo@foobar.co</span></li>
<ol>
```

Inserting a span around the comment seems to fix the issue for me.